# Possible output of a firm using game theory

Tags: calculus, game-theory, nash-equilibrium

Let there be two firms A and B. Let the price(P) output(X) graph be a linear one $P =a-bX=5-(1)X,c=2$
The parameter

1. a is MAX price.
2. b is the slope of the curve profit vs output(line)
3. c is the price at perfect competitive market ie large number of firms.

Now firm A wants to put a production unit.Both firms A and B are rational and A knows that B is rational. No firm has negative amount of production. Using the knowledge 
of game theory and Nash equilibrium choose the options which the firm A can produce. $$\text{The option set(in some proper units)}$$

$A\in(0,
0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1 ,1.25, 1.5, 1.75 ,2)$
$$\text{Attempt}$$
Clearly the firm wont produce 0 units so it isn't one of the choices.Now we know from Nash equilibrium that total output for $N$ firms is $(1-\frac{1}{N+1})(\frac{a-c}{b})$.Here $N=2$ and putting in other values we see the total ouput$=2$. Also at equilibrium the players(firms)mutually take the best option available so each firm produces same quantity. Hence each firm's produce is $=1$.So $1$ is the equilibrium production. Now we know firms are rational but that doesn't mean that A will have the best reply right from the beginning. It may eventually start producing $1$ units. So other options do exist for firm A. We know that the profit vs output curve is quadratic $\text{Profit of A}=k(\frac{a-c}{b}-B-A)A$ where $$\text{A,B are outputs of the respective firms.}$$ I dont know how to proceed to see which other options are available to A.
$$\text{Note:}$$ Assume I have no knowledge of economics so if possible limit your answer to basics of maths and game theory.
$$\text{Edit}$$
In part b I was asked that if B doesn't know that he is rational then which of the above outputs would the firm A never choose.

Answer (score 1):

1. Write out a payoff matrix, often called the strategic form.  Here it is a $9 \times 9$ matrix/tableau with the quantities along the left side and the top, with two numbers in the $(i,j)$ box, one the payoff for row and the other the payoff for column when row plays $q_i \in A$ and column plays $q_j \in A$:
   $$
   \pi_{row}(q_i,q_j) = (A-b(q_i+q_j))q_i - cq_i
   $$
   and
   $$
   \pi_{col}(q_i,q_j) = (A-b(q_i+q_j))q_j - cq_j.
   $$
   Include every strategy, including zero: there are often surprising equilibria where agents adopt strategies you might not expect.
2. Construct the best reply correspondence for each player. Fix a column, and find the highest payoff for the row player, and underline; do this for all columns. Fix a row, and find the highest payoff for the column player, and underline; do this for all rows. In general, this correspondence exists and is upper hemi-continuous (by extending the pure strategies to random, mixed strategies) by Berge's Theorem of the Maximum.
3. Solve for a fixed point of the best reply correspondences, which is a Nash equilibrium. Find all boxes where both payoffs are underlined. In your game there are probably three-ish. In general, a pure-strategy equilibrium might not exist, but if you allow for random strategies, you can use Kakutani's fixed-point theorem along with convexity and upper hemi-continuity of the best-reply correspondences to prove existence of a fixed point (i.e., a Nash eqm).

That is all of game theory in a nutshell: solve for best reply correspondences for the players (use Berge's Theorem), then find a fixed point using Brouwer, Kakutani, Tarski, Glicksberg, Schauder, Banach, Eilenberg-Montgomery, or whatever the appropriate FPT is.

This game is actually solvable by iterated deletion of weakly dominated strategy, which is an epistemically stronger concept than Nash equilibrium: for each player, remove any strategy where there exists an alternative strategy that always gives a weakly higher payoff, and repeat until no further strategies can be deleted for either player. That is one way of picking a unique equilibrium in situations where there are multiple Nash equilibria, and it will be the closest one to the continuous version of the eqm you posted.

I guess the issue is that you solved the continuous version of the model using calculus. The discrete version ($A$ is finite) is going to have multiple eqa, and the question is asking, "What values in $A$ correspond to a Nash eqm for the row player?"  A more sophisticated question would be, ``What values in $A$ are rationalizable: i.e., constitute a best reply to some strategy that the column player might use?"  If you take the iterated deletion route, the unique answer as a result of common knowledge of rationality will be the Nash strategies.

Comment: I appreciate your really neat step wise approach howeverI have started game theory two weeks back and have very general if not vague idea about what you mentioned in para 3.Cant the problem be solved with very basic game theory knowledge?

Comment: If you write out the payoff matrix for $A \times A$, then do the underlining as in para ii, the boxes where both payoffs are underlined twice are the Nash eqa (the fixed points of the best reply correspondence).  If you do step 1 and 2 it will be obvious by inspecting the payoff matrix what is going on in step 3. Nash eqm is just a pair of strategies for each player where neither can strictly benefit by deviating, given the proposed strategy of the opponent.

Comment: Okay I did it wrong the first time but I tried it again. When one of the q's is 0 we get 5 as the payoff and it is max in that particularrowor column so the only box where I got both underlined are just thefirstone with 5,5 as the payoff.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the game $G = \langle\{1,2\},(A_1,A_2),(u_1,u_2)\rangle$ where $i \in \{1,2\}$ denotes a firm, $A_i = \{0,0.25,\ldots,1.75,2.0\}$ the action space of firm $i$ and $u_i : A_1 \times A_2 \to \mathbb R$ with $u_i(a_1,a_2) = (5 - a_1 - a_2)a_i - 2a_i$ the utility/payoff function of firm $i$.

**Approach**: Solve the continuous version for an equilibrium $(\bar a_1,\bar a_2) \in \mathbb R^2$ and check whether $(\bar a_1,\bar a_2) \in A_1 \times A_2$.

**Claim**: The game $G$ exhibits an equilibrium at $(a_1,a_2) = (1,1)$.

Let $\text{BR}_2(a_1) = (3-a_1)/2 = \arg\max_{a_2}u_2(a_1,a_2)$ denote the best response of firm 2. Consider the first order condition for maximizing $u_1$ evalutated at $a_2 = \text{BR}_2(a_1)$
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial u_1(a_1,\text{BR}_2(a_1))}{\partial a_1} = 3(1-a_1)/2 = 0.
\end{align}
We thus found an equilibrium candidate at $(a_1,a_2) = (1,\text{BR}_2(1)) = (1,1)$. Since the following conditions are true, it is an equilibrium:
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial u_i(1,1)}{\partial a_i} &= 0 \quad \forall i,\\[3mm]
\frac{\partial^2 u_i(a_1,a_2)}{\partial a_i^2} &= -2 \quad \forall i.
\end{align}

**Edit**

Consider the payoff matrices below. Now we have to carefully identify the optimal response of each agent given the action of the other agent. Agent 1 is the row player. Best responses: If $a_2 = 0$, then the best response of 1 is BR$_1(0) = 1.5$ with payoff $u_1(1.5,0) = 2.25$. If $a_2 = 0.25$, then the best response of 1 is BR$_1(0.25) = \{1.25,1.5\}$ with payoff $u_1(a_1,0.25)|_{a_1 \in \text{BR}_1(0.25)} = 1.88$. And so forth.

You will see that BR$_1(0.75)=\{1,1.25\}$, BR$_1(1)=\{1\}$, BR$_1(1.25)=\{0.75,1\}$ and BR$_2(0.75)=\{1,1.25\}$, BR$_2(1)=\{1\}$, BR$_2(1.25)=\{0.75,1\}$.

Since $1.25 \in \text{BR}_1(0.75)$ and $0.75 \in \text{BR}_2(1.25)$, there exists a Nash equilibrium at $(a_1,a_2) = (1.25,0.75)$. In total there are three equilibria 
\begin{align}
\text{NE}(G) = \{(0.75,1.25),(1,1),(1.25,0.75)\}.
\end{align}

```
u1 =

[     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,      0,      0,      0]
[ 0.688, 0.625, 0.562,   0.5, 0.438, 0.375,  0.312,   0.25,  0.188]
[  1.25,  1.12,   1.0, 0.875,  0.75, 0.625,    0.5,  0.375,   0.25]
[  1.69,   1.5,  1.31,  1.12, 0.938,  0.75,  0.562,  0.375,  0.188]
[   2.0,  1.75,   1.5,  1.25,   1.0,  0.75,    0.5,   0.25,      0]
[  2.19,  1.88,  1.56,  1.25, 0.938, 0.625,  0.312,      0, -0.312]
[  2.25,  1.88,   1.5,  1.12,  0.75, 0.375,      0, -0.375,  -0.75]
[  2.19,  1.75,  1.31, 0.875, 0.438,     0, -0.438, -0.875,  -1.31]
[   2.0,   1.5,   1.0,   0.5,     0,  -0.5,   -1.0,   -1.5,   -2.0]

u2 =

[ 0, 0.688,  1.25,  1.69,  2.0,   2.19,   2.25,   2.19,  2.0]
[ 0, 0.625,  1.12,   1.5, 1.75,   1.88,   1.88,   1.75,  1.5]
[ 0, 0.562,   1.0,  1.31,  1.5,   1.56,    1.5,   1.31,  1.0]
[ 0,   0.5, 0.875,  1.12, 1.25,   1.25,   1.12,  0.875,  0.5]
[ 0, 0.438,  0.75, 0.938,  1.0,  0.938,   0.75,  0.438,    0]
[ 0, 0.375, 0.625,  0.75, 0.75,  0.625,  0.375,      0, -0.5]
[ 0, 0.312,   0.5, 0.562,  0.5,  0.312,      0, -0.438, -1.0]
[ 0,  0.25, 0.375, 0.375, 0.25,      0, -0.375, -0.875, -1.5]
[ 0, 0.188,  0.25, 0.188,    0, -0.312,  -0.75,  -1.31, -2.0]
```

Comment: There would be 81 such combinations is that manually possible?

Comment: i got 0.75,1 is it correct?

Comment: That's very helpful! Just a query? We know(as player A) that B is rational but B may not be knowing that he is rational. Even in that case would the best response to any response b takes from [0-3] those 3 NE are the best ones. Ie firm A wont ever produce 0,0.25,0.5,1.5,1.75,2?

Comment: Hint which was given was that B can produce any real number from [0-3] then which outputs would firm A never choose in that case? Also to use IEDS . (I really cant figure out how to deal with it.